# Apply residue formula 1

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

This seems to be a bit of a stupid question, but I can't get it right and need som help.

I've a formula that says:
If
$$f(z) = (z-a)^{-N}g(z)$$
then
$$Res_{z=a} f(z) = \frac{g^{N-1}(a)}{(N-1)!} $$

I got a dubble pole in $z=3i$ and a function $$g(z) = \frac{e^{2iz}}{(z^2+9)^2}$$

No my problem is to apply the forumula to the function. I get that $ N = 2$ and $z=3i$ but that gives that the demoninator becomes 0 and that's not right.

Answer (score 1):

Note that here, $N=4.$

$$f(z) = 
\frac{e^{2iz}}{(z+3i)^2}(z-3i)^{-2}
$$

Now compute the $(N-1)$th derivative of $g$:
$$
g'(z) = \frac{2ie^{2iz}(z+4i)}{(z+3i)^3}
$$
and evaluate:
$$
Res = g'(3i) = -\frac{7ie^{-6}}{108}
$$